# Translate CircleFitByKasa in MATLAB to Python

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy

Dear all: I have no experience with MATLAB but some experience with Python. I'm trying to translate the MATLAB `CircleFitByKasa` function to Python.

The `CircleFitByKasa` function has the following code:

```
function Par = CircleFitByKasa(XY)
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
%  
%     Simple algebraic circle fit (Kasa method)
%      I. Kasa, "A curve fitting procedure and its error analysis",
%      IEEE Trans. Inst. Meas., Vol. 25, pages 8-14, (1976)
%
%     Input:  XY(n,2) is the array of coordinates of n points x(i)=XY(i,1), y(i)=XY(i,2)
%
%     Output: Par = [a b R] is the fitting circle:
%                           center (a,b) and radius R
%
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
P = [XY ones(size(XY,1),1)] \ [XY(:,1).^2 + XY(:,2).^2];
Par = [P(1)/2 , P(2)/2 , sqrt((P(1)^2+P(2)^2)/4+P(3))];
end   %  CircleFitByKasa
```

I have translated two python code for the same MATLAB function, and the python codes are shown below.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import sys
import open3d as o3d
import math

pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud('C:\\Users\\wilso\\python\\datasets\\PCD\\rail_pcd_points.pcd')
XY=np.asarray(pcd.points)[:,:2]
def circiebykasa1(XY):
    P=np.linalg.solve(np.concatenate((XY, np.ones((len(XY),1))), axis=1), (XY[:,0]**2 + XY[:,1]**2))
    Par=(P[0]/2 , P[1]/2 , np.sqrt((np.power(P[0],2)+np.power(P[1],2))/4+P[2]))
    return Par

def circiebykasa2(XY):
    P=np.linalg.lstsq(np.concatenate((XY, np.ones((len(XY),1))), axis=1),(np.power(XY[:,0],2) + np.power(XY[:,1],2)))
    Par=(P[0]/2 , P[1]/2 , np.sqrt((np.power(P[0],2)+np.power(P[1],2))/4+P[2]))
    return Par
```

The translated Python code could run without any traceback, but the result seems a bit wired to me. According to the comment in the MATLAB code, the MATLAB function should return the center `(a,b)` and the radius `r` of the fitted circle; therefore, I'm assuming that `a`, `b`, and `r` should be single numbers (since the input array `(XY)` is in 2D). However, both my translated Python function shows me the following result.

```
(array([ -49.44680817,  -65.29780001, -974.3765832 ]),
 array([1.47859859e+09]),
 array([1.47859859e+09, 1.47859859e+09, 1.47859859e+09]))
```

According to the result, my parameter `a` and `r` are 3D coordinates which do not make too much sense. Could anyone please kindly have a look and let me know where I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function numpy.linalg.lstsq() returns more than just the least square solution.

I think changing this:

```
Par=(P[0]/2 , P[1]/2 , np.sqrt((np.power(P[0],2)+np.power(P[1],2))/4+P[2]))
```

to this:

```
Par=(P[0][0]/2 , P[0][1]/2 , np.sqrt((np.power(P[0][0],2)+np.power(P[0][1],2))/4+P[0][2]))
```

should fix it. But I cannot check as I do not have your data.